# 1987 skidoo elan carb issues

Tags: carburetor, small-engine

I am trying to figure out either what model carb I have (to purchase a rebuild kit) or spec settings on the fuel/air jets.   Tried to start her up tonight, ran for a minute then got flooded.  Anything will help, thank you.

Comment: Have you got the manual - that normally explains how to set the carb...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!